# Modal Body content gets replaced : Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am developing a website by using twitter bootstrap, smarty,jquery and php. and I am very new to Bootstrap.

So I have prepared a page which collect applicant data.

**html content** :

```
{include file="admin/admin.header.tpl"}
<div class="summary">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Applicant Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Mobile No.</th>
                <th>Details<th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {foreach from=$totalApplicantSummary key=key item=value}
                <tr>
                    <td>{$value.applicant_name}</td>
                    <td>{$value.email}</td>
                    <td>{$value.mobile}</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="?e={$value.email}&fid={$formId}" data-target="#myModal" data-keyboard="false">view more</a></td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >
            <h1>Hi</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
    </div>
</div>
{include file="admin/admin.footer.tpl"}
```

NB: **admin.footer.tpl** contains bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js .

**What I want to do?**

To view total applicant data I have given **view more** link which will be displayed  in a
MODAL.

I have defined the modal as "#myModal" and for testing **"HI...."** as MODAL BODY CONTENT.

**What is my problem?**

**View more** link shows **MODAL** which contains the  previous content (total page i.e applicant name, email, mobile along with header ,footer) instead of "HI....".

So how to display **Hi...** instead of the whole page content.

thanks in advance.

For better reference to problem images of output are provided.

Before view more link is clicked :

[image]

Modal content after the link is clicked:

[image]

Comment: can you please refer us the test page ... will be easier for us to help you that way . thanks

Comment: @Shail : Do I need to attach images of rendered pages?

Comment: it will be good if you can create a test page

Comment: @Shail I have attached the images

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though you're trying to make the modal grab the content of a remote page.

Checkout the following [page](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMofRZ?p=preview) for an example of using remote pages with Modals in Bootstrap.

Basically, if a remote url is provided, content will be loaded via jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-body. If you're using the data api, you may alternatively use the href tag to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">click me</a>
```

If you are not trying to pull data from a remote page, then your issue is that your href tag needs to contain the ID of the modal, ie: #myModal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```